# How we can get a variable from the user in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

How can we get a variable from the user in Ruby?

Comment: Ask him for it.

Answer (score 2):

```
puts "Enter something i will store it"

my_variable = gets.chomp
```

Comment: tnx! But where the user enter the input?

Comment: @TamarRz console http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/Tutorial/part_02/user_input.html

Comment: fine! do you know how we can search Files with ".in" suffix?